# How can we handle questions that are dynamic and change over time?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Some questions are asked about concrete situation at a moment of time. For example [What has trump accomplished in his first term?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/54026/what-has-trump-accomplished-in-his-first-term).

As long as situation changes, answers may fade out.

Maybe such "dynamic" questions should be handled some other way?

Comment: TBH I think they are just bad questions if the correct answer can be entirely different a year later. SE is just not intended for those kinds of Qs, given how voting, HNQ etc. work. No amount of tagging or bounty-ing is going to improve on that.

Comment: "What has trump accomplished in his first term?" isn't necessarily like that because the "first term" definitely ends at a point in time after which answers shouldn't depend on time. I think that Q is more likely to be a problem in terms of opinion-based answers and [in]completeness of the list. What one considers an accomplishment worth mentioning may be "in the eye of the beholder".

Comment: The answer tried to salvage the Q by relating what Trump did to what he had promised (during the campaign), but the Q itself wasn't [restricted] like that at all. Ultimately that Q was closed as duplicate [of another](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42185/what-has-donald-trump-accomplished-as-a-president-objectively), which was itself closed as POB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It worth noting that there's a post notice for these very questions:

> This post relates to a rapidly changing event.

Only ♦ moderators can apply and remove these notices.

There are currently two questions on Politics Stack Exchange which have this notice:

- [What options are left, if Britain cannot decide?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/39405/10072)
- [Did Erdoǧan cheat in the 2018 election?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/31747/10072)

You can find these with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1252918/current-event-posts).

Comment: On some sites in the network, you can flag posts you think deserve this notice for moderator attention. I hope the moderators here will read this and let us know if that works for them too.

Comment: This is a good notice to have (I assume you get added to a question by flagging it for moderator attention?), but how does it help us deal with answers that become out of date due to changing events?

Comment: @divibisan I guess that if moderators use it more often, we can use the SEDE query to check once in a while whether the answers are still up to date (and perhaps flag the post again if the notice isn't warranted anymore).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest placing a bounty on the question with outdated answers. There is even an option for this on the bounty dialog:

[image]

In the specific case linked in this question, the original suggested duplicate question was closed for being opinion-based, so a bounty couldn't be started in this situation. However, as the community decided that the original was opinion-based, it seems likely that the new question will attract the same sentiment.

I would also point out that the [only answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54027/28994) to the new question at the time of writing is just an updated version of the user's [older answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/42186/28994) to the proposed duplicate, which seems to reinforce the appropriateness of placing a bounty to encourage answers to be updated.

Comment: That is a good approach, but sadly not available for everyone. Low reputation users may be unable to do so or lose privileges for it. So if they are interested in an up-to-date answer they will ask a new question.

Comment: @miep: Unfortunately, if everyone could draw attention to everything, then no one would be able to draw attention to anything.